# 18 and 19.10 Desktop dimmers not working with Radeon drivers

Tags: brightness, amd-graphics

I reinstalled my graphics card driver and now I can't dim the screen anymore on my desktop.

When I use this https://github.com/sidneys/desktop-dimmer/releases
it prevents me from clicking on the dock and top toolbar. I have to kill it from the terminal to stop it.

This doesn't adjust anything. 
https://github.com/Fushko/gammy 
Not working in Ubuntu 18:
[image]

Not working in 19.1:
[image]

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
1920x1080 59.96*+
```

/sys/class/backlight directory is empty

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My computer was using a wayland session.

```
sudo vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

and uncomment

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux